# text-field derived class font does not work in Racket

Tags: fonts, textbox, scheme, racket

I am trying to create a text-field derived class with a particular font. The field gets created all right but the font does not work:

```
#lang racket/gui 

; my particular font: 
(define (myfont size)  (make-object font% size 'modern 'normal 'bold))

(define myframe (new frame% [width 600] [label "MyFrame"]))  

(new text-field% [parent myframe] [label "Usual text-field; font works here:"] [font (myfont 14)])

; Following is my text-field derived class with a particular font: 
(define mytf% (class text-field%  (field (font (myfont 14))) (super-new)))
(new mytf% [parent myframe] [label "My text-field derived class; font does not work here:"])

(send myframe show #t)
```

Where is the problem and how can it be solved? Thanks for your comments/answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `font` is not a public field in `text-field%`. 
Therefore the `(field (font (myfont 14)))` makes a new field visible in `mytf%` but not used by `text-field%`.

The solution is to pass the font information when the text-field is instantiated:

```
(define mytf%
  (class text-field%
    (super-new [font (myfont 14)])))
```